# How to get URL from amazon s3 using laravel 5.2 Storage::get() not working

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I was able to save file in my amazon s3 using Intervention and now i need to get the URL of my image from s3. And as indicated in laravel 5.2 documentation retrieving file is just like this,

```
$contents = Storage::get('file.jpg');
```

but when i tried the code and dump it. it ouputs nothing. I've already changed the permission of the folder in my bucket.

this is my code:

```
    $file = Storage::get('products/3b2f81c6-7f73-4df8-a52f-82f60f50947a/cebadge.png');
    dd($file);
```

I installed the aws sdk and will try to work on it for now. I've already read most of the articles about this, but I really have no luck getting near a solution. can someone lead me to the right path. thank you.

code to save image in s3, just sharing

```
$folderName = $request->input('folname')."/";
    $img = Image::make($file);
    $origName = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
 Storage::put($s3Bucket.'/'.$directory.'/'.$folderName.'/'.$origName, $img->__toString());
```

Comment: any articles that I should read?

Comment: okay, now i know why i'm getting nothing every time I used storage::get() it's because my code for uploading is wrong! lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after much for reading AWS SDK for PHP documentation and articles online now I finally understand how it works, well the basic ones.

My problem turned out to be not getting the file but saving the file into s3.

I was using the code above (see my question above) to upload a file. it was the wrong code. what's wrong with it? I didn't convert the file into stream before casting it to string then uploading to s3. what I did was to cast it directly to string and upload it. that's why i'm getting nothing when I used storage::get().

wrong code:

```
$img = Image::make($file);
    $origName = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
 Storage::put($s3Bucket.'/'.$directory.'/'.$folderName.'/'.$origName, $img->__toString());
```

and what else is wrong here. the bucket name, you don't have to specify the bucket name else it will create a folder.

right code:

```
$image = $request->file('file'); //the image
        $img = Image::make($file); // using interventation
 $image_normal = $img->stream(); // to stream
Storage::put($origName, $image_normal->__toString(),'public'); //to string
```

and to make the file publicly available, just include a 3rd parameter 'public' else it will automatically make it private.

to sum it up. what you need to do to upload and use s3 files for your website is the following.

1. Create your account in AWS s3, just follow the instructions in laravel 5.2 documentation for setting up the filesystems.php in config\ folder
2. set the default storage to s3

'default' => 's3',

3. uploading an image

   ```
   $origName = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
   $image = $request->file('file');
   $img = Image::make($file);
   $image_normal = $img ->stream();
   Storage::put($origName, $image_normal->__toString(),'public');
   ```
4. getting the URL of an image is as simple as below URL

   https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/citibanko.PNG

   https://s3-[region].amazonaws.com/[yourbucketname]/filename.PNG
5. additionally if you want to list the names of the file in your bucket use below code:

   $files = Storage::files('/');
       dump($files);

for the folders

$files = Storage::files('foldername');
        dump($files);

in amazon s3 sub directories are really irrelevant, it's bucket and file names only.